# Telnet sub negotiation command without IAC SE

Tags: ftp, telnet

Does telnet sub negotiation command without IAC SE is valid command?

Answer (score 0):

No, the IAC, SE sequence indicates the end of the response (and the supplied value).

See [Documentation](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/node141.html)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Robert Bradley says, a sub-option negotiation which does not end with `<IAC><SE>` is NOT valid.

However there is one *unofficial* exception, which, because it was broken like that, got replaced, but theoretically could be *seen in the wild*. That is the original version of the **M**ud **C**lient **C**ompression **P**rotocol (MCCP) - using sub-option number 85 which uses `zlib` compression to reduce the amount of data bytes to be sent from a MUD (Multi-User Dungeon) Game Server to the players' Clients. That mistakenly has the Server using `<IAC><SB><85><WILL><SE>` at the exact point in the data where compression begins. This defect was so significant that the protocol was revised to version 2 - which is otherwise identical except that it uses the sub-option number 86 instead - so that the sequence to begin that (after both server and client have agreed) is the correctly formed: `<IAC><SB><86><IAC><SE>`.

MUD server and client applications are now to prefer MCCP2 over MCCP1 (and obviously not agree to do the latter if the former has already been negotiated). See also: https://smaugmuds.afkmods.com/mccp/protocol.html.